# Checking for string value in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I'm trying to check if this string has any value or not.

Making this check :

```
if (!nValue.isEmpty) {
>> Breakpoint    
.
.
.
}
```

The debugger at breakpoint shows me the string is nil

[image]

Is the string really nil? Is there a better way to check the text in string in this case? I'm looking for something on lines of

`[self.nValue isEqualToString: @""]` from objective-C

Comment: Looks like the string is "nil", not nil...

Comment: @WillM.Yup, that was it. Classic FML situation. SMH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the string gets value "nil" when I assign it from a NSNumber, and that `num.integerValue` is 0